# MacOS/Debian10 dual boot- how to delete unknown EFI partition?

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, macos

I have a macbook air dual booting macOS Catalina and Debian10 buster. I hold the option key at startup to choose the system I want. In the boot manager there's this efi partition (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BblY.jpg) that I would like to delete, because it starts nothing but grub bash minimal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPOJA.jpg), but I have not been able to identify this partition neither from macOS 'diskutils' nor from Debian 'fdisk'.

How could I delete this partition?

[image: Boot loader]
[image: Output of "?" efi entry]

**EDIT**:
That's the output of `efibootmgr -v`:

`BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,30876d26-f04d-42fb-b246-d07cc557c84d,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0080*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)//HD(2,GPT,061cc74a-368d-4be1-b241-b0357cf49450,0x64028,0x239c8b18)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,d33fe668562e454587d38e42e85103da)/File(\EA7C5756-71C9-40BA-BF03-EF8192464A2F\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)//HD(2,GPT,061cc74a-368d-4be1-b241-b0357cf49450,0x64028,0x239c8b18)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,d33fe668562e454587d38e42e85103da)/File(\EA7C5756-71C9-40BA-BF03-EF8192464A2F\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)`

It is called ubuntu perhaps because I had a previous Ubuntu installation in dual boot. Maybe that's what is causing the issue. How to solve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you please include your images in your question to ensure they stay available for future readers (links tend to break)? The [Markdown help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) explains how.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

The EFI partition is required to boot into UEFI based OS(s).
UEFI is the modern replacement for BIOS.

Anyways,
If you still want to remove it, live boot into your computer using any OS or a tool like [GParted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php). Note that you might have to change your boot preferences.

Now, open the terminal and type

```
parted
print
```

The first partition (hence 1) is always the EFI partition.

```
select /dev/sdX
rm 1
```

where X depends on the disk on the EFI partition resides.

[If you want to use GParted, here's the documentation:](https://gparted.org/documentation.php)

Comment: I know that they are used to boot, but this specific one labeled in my figure with "?" boots into "nothing" (actually, the output is the grub bash minimal in the second figure). What I want I want is to remove this specific one and keep the ones that boots in Debian and MacOS. I think this may be a file or configuration in a file in Debian's partition.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Linux and use `efibootmgr -v`. Perhaps the extra "EFI partition" is not a partition at all, but actually an extra UEFI boot variable, and removing the non-functional boot variable will fix the problem.

Look at the `BootCurrent:` line of the `efibootmgr -v` output. It will identify the boot entry that the system is currently booted up on (i.e. the entry that got you into Linux in the first place). The `.efi` file pathname on that boot entry should be `\EFI\DEBIAN\GRUBX64.EFI` if no Secure Boot shim is used, or `\EFI\DEBIAN\SHIMX64.EFI` if Secure Boot is in effect.

Alternatively, the extra entry might be caused by the UEFI fallback bootloader, which would be located at `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` when booted into Debian 10. Depending on choices made during the installation of Debian 10, I think the installer may create the fallback bootloader but does not always succeed in creating a good configuration file for it.

The fallback bootloader would be a possible way to access Linux without booting from an external media if the UEFI boot variables are lost in the system NVRAM memory for any reason. Basically, it is the same mechanism that is used to detect UEFI-bootability on USB sticks and other non-iso9660 removable media: if there is a FAT32 partition with a `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` file present on the media, then the media should be presented as UEFI-bootable even if there are no UEFI boot variables referring to it.

The system manufacturer will have the option of extending the UEFI firmware to support booting from filesystem types other than FAT32: I believe some PC motherboards will support UEFI bootloaders on NTFS filesystems, and Apple computers will accept some forms of HFS. But FAT32 is the minimum common factor required by the UEFI specification.

So, if there are no extra UEFI boot variables to remove, the `BootCurrent:` indicates you're successfully booting using the main Debian bootloader, and `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` exists on your system, you can just delete it or rename it to something else to stop the firmware from recognizing it, since it looks like the fallback bootloader is not in a functional state right now.

Comment: I think you may be right, that's what I'm considering now too. I've used efibootmgr, but I did not figure out what is the extra one. In the case of of the fallback bootloader, is there a way I can alter this file or change configurations?

Comment: See my edit above. The question on the alternative bootloader would be easier to answer if you added the `efibootmgr -v` output into your question, please.

Comment: I edited my question and posted the output of the `efibootmgr -v`. Can I simply change to a debian folder instead of ubuntu? And yes, there is `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`  I can access it also through macOS.

Comment: I tried to remove `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` when in macos, but then I couldn't boot into debian, the "? partition" persisted. I had to restore the file.